# pyenv: version shown does not match actual version?

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I am working on [OS X 11.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur), and I have installed `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv`.

I have also installed Python 3.9.6 via pyenv.

However, although pyenv thinks I am using Python 3.9.6...

```
% pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.6 (set by /Users/me/.pyenv/version)
```

...`python` is still defaulting to 2.7.16:

```
% python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

Some more information:

```
% pyenv version
3.9.6 (set by /Users/me/.pyenv/version)

% which python
/usr/bin/python
```

If I do `python3 --version` then I do see 3.9.6. But I'd prefer it if `python` defaulted to this too.

What am I doing wrong? Should I just alias `python` to `python3`?

Comment: Possibly paths for `pyenv` are not added into `PATH`. Or `pyenv` has not been initialized correctly. Please check [pyenv's README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) about how to init `pyenv`.

Comment: There may be system software that still depends on Python2. I'd leave python2 alone and just always use `python3` instead of `python`, but wouldn't alias it as to not break some old code. Macos ships with ancient software, just run `/usr/bin/diff --version`.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there. You need to configure your shell's environment for Pyenv.

I am going to assume you are on zsh, run these commands:

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile

echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Make sure that your terminal app runs the shell as a login shell.
Source: [pyenv GitHub](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

if the version problem persists. Open your ~/.zshrc and paste the following to the bottom:

```
export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"


if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
fi
```

Creating an alias of python to python3 will cause problems for you.